# How to call Operator when WorkSpaceTool is activated？

Tags: scripting

```py
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def modal(self, context, event):

        print("do something")

        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        print("invoke")
        
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


class MyTool(bpy.types.WorkSpaceTool):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_context_mode = 'OBJECT'

    bl_idname = "my_template.my_tool_test"
    bl_label = "My Tool Test"
    bl_description = ""
    bl_icon = "ops.generic.select_circle"
    bl_widget = None
    bl_keymap = None


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_tool(MyTool, after={"builtin.scale_cage"}, separator=True, group=True)
    

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_tool(MyTool, after={"builtin.scale_cage"}, separator=True, group=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

How to call Operator when MyTool is activated？

This is the effect of primitive_cube_add：
[image]

I don’t want to register bl_keymap, it requires at least one mouse click to call Operator